# split a List<Product> into SubLists<Product>

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-objects

I have a List with Categories and Products as properties, and I wish to seperate all the products pertaining to a Category in different lists.

At the moment I have this

```
Products products = new Products();

        products.productList.Add(new Products("Fruit", "Apples"));
        products.productList.Add(new Products("Fruit", "Oranges"));
        products.productList.Add(new Products("Fruit", "Bananas"));
        products.productList.Add(new Products("Fruit", "Grapes"));
        products.productList.Add(new Products("Vegetables", "Tomatoes"));
        products.productList.Add(new Products("Vegetables", "Lettuce"));
        products.productList.Add(new Products("Vegetables", "Onions"));
        products.productList.Add(new Products("Dairy", "Milk"));
        products.productList.Add(new Products("Dairy", "Yogurth"));
        products.productList.Add(new Products("Dairy", "Eggs"));

        List<IEnumerable<string>> distinctCats = products.productList.GroupBy(s => s.Category).Select(s => s.Select(v => v.Product)).ToList();
```

But I cannot seem to get the values from the distinctCats.  And I would like to get something like a normal List productList with actual values.

Thanks for your help and time

Comment: What output are you expecting? A List of distinct categories, or a list of Category with a list of products in that category?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to divide a list into sublists by category:

```
var categoryLists = products.GroupBy(p => p.Category)
                            .Select(g => g.ToList());
```

Now, `categoryLists` is an `IEnumerable<List<Product>>`.

To iterate over this, you can say:

```
foreach(var categoryList in categoryLists) {
    foreach(var product in categoryList) {
        // do something with product
    }        
}
```

Comment: Hi Jason yes I want the var categoryLists = products.GroupBy(p => p.Category)                             .Select(g => g.ToList());  but how can I iterate inside it to get the Category and the list of products?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understood what you  want, but seems you need somthing like this:

```
var products=new List<Product>{};
var productsInCategories=products.ToLookup(p=>p.Category);
```

Now every productsInCategories[i] contains a "subList" (actually IEnumerable) .